# Аналог ref в spring @Configuration

Tags: java, spring

`@Configuration` позволяет внутренние зависимости. Означает ли это, что вызвав метод создания одного бина из другого, можно сымитировать поведение атрибута `ref` тега `<property>` в `xml` конфигурации?

```
@Bean( "bean1" )
public Bean1 bean1() {
  Bean1 bean1 = new Bean1();
  bean1.setBean2(bean2());
  return bean1;
}
@Bean( "bean2" )
public Bean2 bean2() { return new Bean2(); }
```

Равнозначно ли тому же в `xml`

```
<bean id="bean1" class="Bean1">
  <property name="bean2" ref="bean2"/>
</bean>
<bean id="bean2" calss="Bean2"/>
```

Или же для того чтобы добиться такого же результата как в `xml` нужно использовать другой подход?

Answer (score 0):

```
@Bean( "bean1" )
public Bean1 bean1() { return new Bean1(); }

@Bean( "bean2" )
public Bean2 bean2() { return new Bean2(); }

@Component
public class Bean1 {
    @Autowired
    priavate Bean2 bean2;
}
```

либо же, если черет сеттер

```
@Component
public class Bean1 {
    priavate Bean2 bean2;

    @Autowired
    public void setBean2(Bean2 bean2) {
        this.bean2 = bean2;
    }
}
```

Comment: Но в таком случае придется связывать бин со спринговым стеком? Без этого никак?

Comment: @Belenot, не уверен, но если не хотите привязываться к спринговому стеку, то думаю, что ваш вариант тоже будет работать. И думаю да, ваш Configuration вариант все же аналогичен вашему xml варианту

Answer (score 0):

Думаю этот вариант будет ближе к вашему конфигу xml:

```
@Bean( "bean1" )
public Bean1 bean1(Bean2 bean2) {
  Bean1 bean1 = new Bean1();
  bean1.setBean2(bean2);
  return bean1;
}

@Bean( "bean2" )
public Bean2 bean2() { return new Bean2(); }
```

Т.е. когда у метода есть параметры спринг ищет подходящий компонент в своём контексте и сам подставляет. Если не сможет найти, то кинет исключение.

Comment: Честно говоря, я тоже склонен к этому варианту, но как по мне это криво. Допустим, если bean1 установить какой-то не дефолтный  profile и активировать его в контексте, а bean2 оставить нетронутым, то все будет работать и bean2 не входящий в профайл вполне себе создастся. Это нормальное явление?

Comment: Не совсем понял вашу мысль. Т.е. хотите bean1 пометить аннотацией @Profile. То что мешает bean2 этим же профилем аннотировать?